# Why do a paired t-test and lm give different t-values in R?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, lm

I was playing around with some data, trying to get a grip on doing contrasts for within-subjects designs in R. I've noticed that, as far as I can tell, using `lm` or `aov` and `t.test` gives different t-values on the same two-condition data.

Sample data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

tmp <- tibble(a = rnorm(10, 50, 10), b = rnorm(10, 150, 10))

tmpLong <- tmp %>% add_column(., subId = 1:10, .before = 1) %>% 
  pivot_longer(., cols = a:b, names_to = 'block', values_to = 'rt')
```

`lm`:

```r
lm(rt ~ block + subId,
   data = tmpLong) %>% summary
```

gives:

```
Call:
lm(formula = rt ~ block + subId, data = tmpLong)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-23.861  -5.622   2.276   4.130  15.405 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value          Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  48.4819     5.0561   9.589 0.000000028550295 ***
blockb      101.1664     4.2480  23.815 0.000000000000017 ***
subId         0.5164     0.7395   0.698             0.494    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 9.499 on 17 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9709,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9675 
F-statistic: 283.8 on 2 and 17 DF,  p-value: 0.00000000000008714
```

So, for what is essentially a t-test, we get a t-value of 23.815. Now, I get that using `lm` may be inappropriate given that the data are imagined as being within-subjects. But, using `aov` with an `Error` term:

```r
aov(rt ~ block + Error(subId),
    data = tmpLong) %>% summary
```

gives:

```
Error: subId
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals  1     44      44               

Error: Within
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value            Pr(>F)    
block      1  51173   51173   567.2 0.000000000000017 ***
Residuals 17   1534      90                              
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Now, given that this is a two group case, $F$ should be $t^2$, right?
And this is the case, given that $23.815^2 = 567.1542$

But, a t-test:

```r
t.test(tmp$a, tmp$b, paired = T)
```

gives:

```
    Paired t-test

data:  tmp$a and tmp$b
t = -20.728, df = 9, p-value = 0.000000006623
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -112.20741  -90.12543
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
              -101.1664
```

Which is quite close, but not the same. But the estimated difference from the t-test is the same as from `lm`.

Given all of the above, I have to admit that (a) I'm pretty confused about how to approach a within-subjects analysis and (b) contrasts (with more than 2 groups) in R.

Also, since I'm interested in effect sizes, I'd like to now Cohen's $d_z$, which can be calculated as $\frac{t}{\sqrt{N}}$. Using the formula with the different t-values gives (from `lm`/`aov`) 7.531 and (`t.test`) 6.554, respectively (using $N = 10$).

Any clarification is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to convert `subId` to a factor!  Then you will get identical results.

Comment: Oh my God, you are right! Thought R would coerce it, and it didn't even cross my mind that there's not a load of dummies in `lm` output! Thanks a lot! Feel free to post this as an answer. Also feel free to comment on the different approaches if you feel like it :)